# Typo3 formhandler, how to change 'ctrl' 'label' to a 'params' field?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

How to change the formhandler ctrl label from default "uid" to a specific field or fields in the "params" table? If I try to use the params field as label the output looks like a weird object:

```
{a:13:""s:6:"email":s:20:"test@test.com"}
{a:13:""s:7:"email":s:26:"test1@test.com"}
```

More ugly but better than the uid default of just:

```
1234
1235
```

Is there any chance I can change that to something usefull like the email adress or another required field of every record?

Answer (score 0):

**Requires >= TYPO3 7.6:** You will need any extension for this purpose. You have to change the 'label' configuration for tx_formhandler_log adding the following to a TCA override file like this: **yourext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_formhandler_log.php** having this content:

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_formhandler_log']['ctrl']['label'] = 'params';
```

To get something useful as label for those records you would have to extend the formhandler table by a field. Then you have to add Finisher to your forms and write the form values to the new field of your Formhandler table. Then you can change the code above to apply your new field as label.

Doc about FinisherDB: http://www.typo3-formhandler.com/documentation/finisher/finisherdb/